# "Cannot assign image to *UIImageView*" Error in SWIFT (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

Im trying to find the UIImageViews in the view and to assign few images to them based on the tags. But unfortunately i couldn't assign the images to UIImageView variable from an array. I couldn't really resolve the problem.

Below is the code that I wrote.

```
var imageViewSlot = UIImageView()
    for imageViewSlot in self.view.subviews
    {
       if (imageViewSlot .isMemberOfClass(UIImageView))
       {
            for i in 1...imagePieces.count
            {
                if (imageViewSlot.tag == i)
                {
                    imageViewSlot.image = imagePieces[i] as? UIImage //Error in this line
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- in above code `var imageViewSlot = UIImageView()` you gave this as global, and you used same name in **for in** statement that is the main problem. So because of this it donot know which type of object this is, So for that we have to mention like this `(imageViewSlot as UIImageView).image = image`

try below code, and check [this link](http://www.adamzucchi.com/blog/?p=282)

```
 for  imageViewSlot in self.view.subviews
    {
        if (imageViewSlot .isMemberOfClass(UIImageView))
        {
            for i in 1...imagePieces.count
            {
                if (imageViewSlot.tag == i)
                {
                    var image = UIImage(named: imagePieces[i])
                    (imageViewSlot as UIImageView).image = image

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the actual error that i get is, "imageViewSlot" is not even recognised as UIImageView by Xcode completion if I use it in 'for loop'.

If it is recognised as UIImageView, I could easily assign the images to it.

Comment: modified answer check once

Comment: I tried your code. But I get the below error on this line -> "var image = UIImage(named: imagePieces[i])

Error: Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(named: @lvalue AnyObject)'

Comment: did you add this 'var imageViewSlot = UIImageView()' before for loop.

Comment: modified answer check once. If you add this 'var imageViewSlot = UIImageView()' remove and execute code.

Comment: Okay. This worked. But i didn't remove 'var imageViewSlot= UIImageView()'. 
Also i edited this line 'var image = UIImage(named: imagePieces[i])' to 'var image = imagePieces[i] as UIImage'. As imagePieces is an array and we can't assign in string place. 

Anyway. This was really helpful and i learnt. Thank you much. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you're accessing your array with an index outside its bounds. Your `for` loop should be from `0` up to and **not** including `imagePieces.count`.

```
for i in 0..<imagePieces.count
{
    if (imageViewSlot.tag == i)
    {
        imageViewSlot.image = imagePieces[i] as? UIImage //Error in this line
    }
}
```

Second, it looks like you're trying to find a `UIImageView` in your `self.view.subviews`, right? When you do that, you're setting `imageViewSlot` to a `UIView`. I see that you're checking if it's a member of class `UIImageView`, but that doesn't actually change the type of the `imageViewSlot` variable. You'll need to cast `imageViewSlot` to a `UIImageView` to be able to set the `image` property.

I'd do it like this (untested):

```
// Note, you don't need to declare var imageViewSlot first

for subview in self.view.subviews {
    if let imageViewSlot = subview as? UIImageView {
        for i in 0..<imagePieces.count {
            if imageViewSlot.tag == i {
                imageViewSlot.image = imagePieces[i] as UIImage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If your tags are setup correctly, then you really don't need that inner `for` loop either. You can simplify it to something like this:

```
for subview in self.view.subviews {
    if let imageViewSlot = subview as? UIImageView {
        if imageViewSlot.tag >=0 && imageViewSlot < imagePieces.count {
            imageViewSlot.image = imagePieces[imageViewSlot.tag] as UIImage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the actual error that i get is, "imageViewSlot" is not even recognised as UIImageView by Xcode completion if I use it in 'for loop'.

If it is recognised as UIImageView, I could easily assign the images to it.

Comment: Sorry, I missed an additional issue. I edited my answer.

Comment: I tried your answer. Im getting error as "**Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer**" for "**let imageViewSlot as? UIImageView**"